# Why my 7 m/o baby begins to move after first forty minutes of each night sleep

Tags: infant, sleep, sleep-training

Our 7-month-old baby always begins to move after the first 40 minutes of his night sleep (at 9pm). If we can't manage to maintain him sleeping then this breaks his all sleeping routine and he sleeps very late which is bad for him (and for us!). We generally give him the feeding bottle. Although he drinks very little, the bottle helps him relax and he continues to sleep.

I wonder why this might be happening? Anyone with similar experience? Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: What is your typical nighttime routine (bath, reading, feeding, etc)? This may help answer your question.

Comment: Can you give more context on what the goal is and what you’re currently doing that’s not working? What do you mean by he begins to move, do you mean toss and turn? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ours have been restless like this and it was due to some issues with reflux.

Do you notice him making gulping noises or seeming to swallow uncomfortably? If you do, you could talk to your pediatrician about a Zantac prescription.

Other safe alternatives that helped us and are over the counter would be:

1. A soothing formula
2. There is a product we used from Gerber called "Soothe". These are drops that you put in the bottle at night and it helps settle their stomach. I recommend these as they really worked well for us.

As a note, both of these were recommended to us by our pediatrician.

Comment: A non-pharmaceutical approach that has worked fairly well for us is to tilt the crib just a little to raise his head. You can also get foam wedges designed to go under the mattress. The idea is that it helps to stop the reflux from coming up so far, and helps them to swallow it down easier without feeling like they can't breathe, which is scary and guaranteed to have them wake up crying. After our health visitor recommended it, we bought one for our son's crib and it does seem to work. For his pram, I put a thick lever arch file under the mattress, which does about the same thing.

Comment: @anaximander we tried that but unfortunately it wasn't very effective for ours. I am glad you are having success with it though (we prefer non-pharmaceutical approaches when possible too)

Comment: Indeed; the wedge isn't always effective. Here in the UK it's possible to get an infant version of Gaviscon, which helps with reflux and was a real lifesaver when our son's reflux was at its worst. Gerber's Soothe seems to be more of a colic thing than a reflux thing; for that, in the UK there is Infacol, which is similar.

Comment: Only the very slightest of inclines is safe for a sleeping baby, not more than 10%: https://www.webmd.com/parenting/baby/news/20191107/cspc-sleeping-on-an-incline-not-safe-for-baby

Comment: Zantac (Ranitidine) is currently not available in many countries due to concerns that its manufacturing process may be introducing a tiny amount of contamination. There are no directly equivalent drugs approved for infants (at least here in the UK), but proton pump inhibitors (e.g. omaprazole) may be useful